# iScsi Initiator on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iscsi, initiator

Inorder to expand the storage for the HP Proliant DL 380 , MyCloudEX4100 was brought and need to configure as iscsi since these needs to be accessed as local disk for the Exchange the database.

When we select the iScsi initiator , it shows the error "The specified service does not exist as an installed service."The Operating system is Windows 2008 R2.
We have tried to install the iScsi initiator manually by downloading from Microsoft site but no luck.

Please help !!!

Comment: Server 2008r2 comes with the iSCSI initiator installed, did you try this *before* installing it? I seem to remember Microsoft only offer the Target (provider side) as an optional download for 2008r2.

Answer (score 2):

As @tobyd stated, 2008 R2 has the iSCSI service pre-installed. Simply launching it will prompt to enable the service. Reference article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338477(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: For other servers it works fine but for this server , it prompts this message and not able to find the target."The specified service does not exist as an installed service."

Comment: What happens if you try running iSCSICPL.exe?

Answer (score 2):

Run as administrator the `iscsicpl` command to launch the built-in Microsoft iSCSI initiator on Windows Server host. Check [the official manual](https://www.wdc.com/content/dam/wdc/website/downloadable_assets/eng/user_manual/4779-705140.pdf) for or [the video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFc24r9CjyM) to configure iSCSI storage.

Comment: For other servers it works fine but for this server , it prompts this message and not able to find the target."The specified service does not exist as an installed service

Comment: Have you configured iSCSI target properly?

Comment: Yes.The same target is visible under a different server when we tried.